# Laravel and JavaScript : How to reload elements after video play finished

Tags: javascript, laravel, controller, html5-video

I have this video player :

```
<video oncontextmenu="return false;" width="100%" height="auto" controls id="player" controls controlsList="nodownload" disablePictureInPicture  poster="{{asset('images/'.$course->id.'.png')}}" onended="update({{$order->id}} , {{$order->lession_id}})">
    <source src="{{asset('lectures/'.$course->id.'/'.$order->lession_id.'.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="{{asset('lectures/'.$course->id.'/'.$order->lession_id.'.mp4')}}" type="video/ogg">
</video>
```

after it is end I want to update lession_id data ,I create route and controller like this :

```
Route::post('/lession/{order_id}/{lession_id}', [App\Http\Controllers\user\User_controller::class, 'update_lession'])->name('update_lession');
```

method in User Controller

```
public function update_lession($order_id , $lession_id)
{
    $orders=Order::where('id',$order_id);
    $orders->lession_id = $lession_id+1;
    if ($orders->save()){
        return back();
    };
}
```

I tried to use JavaScript but don't work :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function update(order_id , lession_id){
        $.ajax({
            url : 'update_lession',
            type:'POST',
            cache: false,
            data :{
                'order_id' :order_id,
                'lession_id':lession_id,
            }
            success: function(dataResult){
                console.log
            }
        })
    }
</script>
```

How can I do this? and where is the error ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by adding this attribute to video ,and remove the script :

```
data-href="{{URL::to('lession/'.$order->id.'/'.$order->lession_id)}}"
onended="window.location.href = $(this).data('href');"
```

the final video div code :

```
    <video data-href="{{URL::to('lession/'.$order->id.'/'.$order->lession_id)}}" oncontextmenu="return false;" width="100%" height="auto" controls id="player" controls controlsList="nodownload" disablePictureInPicture  poster="{{asset('images/'.$course->id.'.png')}}" onended="window.location.href = $(this).data('href');">
        <source src="{{asset('lectures/'.$course->id.'/'.$order->lession_id.'.mp4')}}" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="{{asset('lectures/'.$course->id.'/'.$order->lession_id.'.mp4')}}" type="video/ogg">
    </video>
```